# BigQuery upload API - is there a way of adding multiple nullMarkers?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm using `Python API` to upload TSV data into *BigQuery*, but I'm faced with situation where my TSV has bunch of "." and "-" signs, I want to treat both as NULLs.

I know I can set `LoadJobConfig()` attribute called `null_marker` to string, and that string will be treated as NULL during the upload.

From [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs):

> [Optional] Specifies a string that represents a null value in a CSV file. For example, if you specify "\N", BigQuery interprets "\N" as a null value when loading a CSV file. The default value is the empty string. If you set this property to a custom value, BigQuery throws an error if an empty string is present for all data types except for STRING and BYTE. For STRING and BYTE columns, BigQuery interprets the empty string as an empty value.

**Question:** But is there a way of using multiple null markers?

The files I work with are very large and it is not efficient to go trough file and replace "-" with "." or vice-versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `null_marker` is not designed for this.

You should let the whole import to go into BigQuery, then do a query and rewrite the same table with NULLed values.

In you use streaming API you already loading the files line by line and hence you can change on your side as well. 
If you upload files, you may want to reconsider automatic this using GCS - > Cloud Functions -> BigQuery (and optionally) -> Query and rewrite table with the NULLed values as well. Doing this you only need to publish your files to GCS and there automatically they will be loaded, files can be kept or deleted by the Function, and the function can trigger additional steps as well, like rewriting with NULLed values.

Comment: The thing is, I have schema where one specific field is double, and when I upload the data it fails because it can not parse "-" as double, I'm using nullMarker because of this... And I can not  "let the whole import to go into BigQuery" because import itself will fail.

Comment: create a schema with string columns and import into that, then you SAFE.CAST the value without error to Double: read this: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators